# How can I return value from completion block?

Tags: swift

I need to perform some code inside completion block of dataTaskWithRequest. This code has to wait for network fetch to finish and then build UI returning UIView. Problem is that I get compiler error about returning value in void function.

Code looks like this

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {

    var rating:Double?

    var id = Int(marker.userData["orgId"] as! String)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlToFetchFrom)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "org_id=\(id!)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {

        data, response, error in

        var json = JSON(data: data!)

        rating = json["results"]["avg_stars"].doubleValue

        self.window = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("infoWindow", owner: self, options: nil).first! as! infoWindow

        self.window?.name.text = marker.title
        self.window?.adress.text = marker.snippet

        if rating != 0 {

            self.window?.stars.image = UIImage(named: "\(self.showStars(rating!))")
            self.window?.rating.text = String(rating!)
        }


        return self.window

    }

    task.resume()        

}
```

How can I modify code so it dont give me compiler errors ?

Comment: Why do you need to return the window?

Answer (score 0):

You can't return from a void closure, not lease because the completion handler could be running at some point in the near future, after the current execution has left your function. Why can't you just call the `resume()` function from within the completion handler?